# Java installed, command not working

Tags: java, software-installation, openjdk

I have installed java but I could not get any java command to work! Below shows what I get when I try to run java commands:

```
sultan@ubuntu:~$ java
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

sultan@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
[sudo] password for sultan:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: My java executable (from openjdk) is in /usr/bin. Is the executable there on your system? Is /usr/bin not on your path for some reason (do `echo $PATH` to see).

Comment: What's the output of `update-java-alternatives -l`?

Comment: I installed sun jdk.. it seems to have been successfully installed. THANKS GUYS

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please consider closing your question or, better yet, [answer it yourself](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Thanks :)